# Issue in including PIE.htc

Tags: spring, css, internet-explorer

We have an issue in including PIE.htc file

it works when we include in html file, but it is not working when we tried to include in spring

In spring we have defined the resource servlet for urls with static

`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

We have placed the PIE.htc in css folder

I also included mime-type in web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>htc</extension>
    <mime-type>text/x-component</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

When I tried the url

`http://testUrl:8080/testproject/static/css/PIE.htc`, getting 404 
also the content type is still text/html

Could you please help me in fixing this

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, sharing the solution for those who experience the same issue.

Create a new JSP file and include the PIE.htc in that jsp file, make sure that the JSP and PIE.htc are in the same location

Include the PIE.jsp in the CSS file instead of the PIE.htc, so the css change would be like

> behavior: url(pie.jsp);

thank you all

Regards
Hari